# Formula To Determine Percentage Between Two Numbers After Certain Threshold

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, divisibility

I have a formula I use to determine how opaque some validation text should be based upon the length of a user's input compared to the maximum lenth allowed.  I want to modify it so that the "ramping up" of the opacity percentage only starts when they are at 80% of max, and then scales up proportionally from there.

Here is my current function:

**OpacityPercentage = CharactersEntered / MaxCharacters**

Therefore, if I have MaxCharacters of 50, then the opacity is as follows:

- 30 chars = 60%
- 40 chars = 80%
- 41 chars = 82%
- 45 chars = 90%
- 50 chars = 100%

What I want is for the opacity to be 0% until I get to 80% of max, then scale up from there.  So I would want the table to look as follows:

- 30 chars = 0%
- 40 chars = 0%
- 41 chars = 10%
- 45 chars = 50%
- 50 chars = 100%

I thought this would be simple, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to change in my existing formula.  Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: Could you just take the maximum of $0$ and $( \text {CharactersEntered}-40)\cdot 10$?

Comment: That's it!  I knew it was simple, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.  If you would, can you post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just take the maximum of $0$ and $(\text{CharactersEntered}−40)\cdot10$ (percent)?

Added from the comment:

If you wanted to start the percentages off at $x$ and have them increase linearly to $100$ at $50$ characters, then you are adding $(100-x)/10$ percent for each character over $40$.  The number of characters over 40 is
$$
I=\text{max}\{(0, \text{CharactersEntered}−40\}.
$$
Given $I$, the percentage would be, for $I>0$, $x$  plus $I\cdot {100-x\over 10}$ percent.
We need a function that tells us if $I>0$ for the following, so let $G=0$ if $I\le 0$ and $G=1$ if $I\ge 1$.
Then the formula (probably not the most efficient) is
$$
 G\cdot x +
\text{max}\{(0, \text{CharactersEntered}−40\}\cdot 
{100-x\over 10}.  
$$

Comment: Thanks!  One last question... what if I wanted the threshold to be another value like 60% or 75% (instead of the 80%).  I thought I just needed to change the "x 10" at the end of your equation, but it's not working.  What value would I use to multiply by for these other percentages?

Comment: @bmccleary Sorry, my last comment was a bit off. I expanded the answer to address your question.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.